# Java Flight Recorder - Async I/O support

Tags: java, jvm, jfr, jmc

Does JFR support Async I/O?

I am using Java Flight Recorder (on HotSpot 1.8.0_144) + Mission Control to profile an app.

On the `File IO` tabs of Mission Control, I see orders of magnitude less "activity" than I expected and that I know to be actually happening.
The IO "activity" that I am actually seeing seems to correspond to synchronous file IO, but I am not sure if this is just a coincidence, or a misconfiguration of the JFR on my part.

I did try this on a smaller example (see below), and it feels like the file async events are not being reported.

#### Sync File IO events are reported

```
val inputStream = new FileInputStream("/home/cmhteixeira/Desktop/output.txt")
val outputStream = new FileOutputStream("/home/cmhteixeira/Desktop/output-copy.txt")

inputStream.transferTo(outputStream)
```

#### Async File IO events are not reported

[RxIo](https://github.com/javasync/RxIo)(used below) is a library claiming to use file async IO.

```
import org.javaync.io.AsyncFiles
import java.nio.file.Paths

val inputStream = Paths.get("/home/cmhteixeira/Desktop/output.txt")
val outputStream = Paths.get("/home/cmhteixeira/Desktop/output-copy.txt")

AsyncFiles
  .readAllBytes(inputStream)
  .thenCompose(bytes => AsyncFiles.writeBytes(outputStream, bytes))
  .thenAcceptAsync(index => println("done")/* invoked on completion */)
```

on both the cases above, the `File IO Threshold` is set to `0 ns` when lunching via Java Mission Control.

#### Questions

- Is file async IO not supported?
- What about async socket IO (which I have not tested)?
- If the answer is no, how bad is this considered by the community that uses JFR?

  - It feels like its a big drawback, but I lack context to understand if in practise this matters much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is file async IO not supported?

There are no events for file async I/O.

> What about async socket IO (which I have not tested)?

Not socket either.

> If the answer is no, how bad is this considered by the community that uses JFR? It feels like its a big drawback, but I lack context to understand if in practise this matters much.

It's been a [known issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8075813) for many years, but it has been tricky to implement. JFR does support [Virtual Threads](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/425), which will hopefully reduce the need for using async APIs directly. It's still a preview feature (April 2022)

See this presentation from FOSDEM, 33:00 minutes in.
https://archive.fosdem.org/2020/schedule/event/state_openjdk/

Comment: Thanks! Follow up question: In Java, as I understand, there is non-blocking IO and asynchronous IO. The former relates to `SelectableChannel`'s and `Selector`'s, and the later relates to `AsynchronousSocketChannel`, `AsynchronousFileChannel`, .... . I assume then that JFR won't be able to capture any of these two kinds of events?

Comment: Correct, none of them.